# Establishing TCP socket connection between 2 VMs using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am running 2 Virtual Machines as Client-Server.

One VM is a Windows[Client] and the other VM is a CentOS[Server].

I have written a program[python] to create TCP connections between them.

When I am running both the client and server code on the same machine[server as localhost], the script works fine and I can see the TCP connections being established. But when I run the scripts separately[client script on windows and server script on CentOS] the TCP connections are not being made.

Both VMs are pingable from each other however.

Is there something I am missing?

Following is the client side script. When I change server name from "local host" to the server IP,   no connection is made.

```
# Client Side Script

from socket import *
server_name = 'localhost' #DOES NOT WORK WHEN REPLACED WITH SERVER IP
server_port = 7000
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((server_name,server_port))

while True:
  sentence = input(">> ")
  client_socket.send(sentence.encode())
  message = client_socket.recv(2048)
  print (">> ", message.decode())
  if(sentence == 'q'):
    client_socket.close()
```

Following is the firewall conf on my CentOS Server. If it helps:

```
user#sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
  public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens160
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 1234(changed)/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: The client code looks fine to me. What kind of error is reported when the connection fails? What does the server code look like? And more importantly, what kind of VMs are you using (VMWare? VirtualBox? Other?), and how have you configured the networking system between the 2 VMs?

Comment: Server code is a basic code where the server binds and listens on port 7000.  Actually, there are no errors reported. But I dont see any TCP connections made when I use "netstat" or "ss -t -a" on my CentOS server. But I see the connections being made successfully when I run both server and client code on the same machine (On CentOS server with local host). So, like you said, I am guessing the error is not a python based error, but something to do with the VM conf or network conf

Comment: And yes, I am using a VMWare hypervisor. Both the Windows Client and  CentOS server are running on this same VMware hypervisor.

Comment: Please show the actual server code, to rule out any mistakes in it. Either the client is connecting successfully, or it is failing with an error, you can't not connect without an error. Maybe the client connects and then disconnects before you can check netstat/ss? We don't know, as we can't see everything you are doing. "As for VMWare, how have you configured its virtual network adapters? VMWare provides extensive documentation on creating networks between VMs, between VMs and the Host, etc.

Comment: What does running `ip addr` in a terminal in CentOS show, and similarly `ipconfig /all` in windows?

Comment: On my Windows client, it shows my IP address of the client (say 10.x.x.x IP). On the server side, again it is a 10.x.x.x IP. Both are pingable from each other. Also, the IP on the server is what I am having on my scripts too.

Comment: Edited the question by adding F/W conf

Comment: Can you ping the server on port 7000? You may need to open the specific port on your firewall.

Comment: I am able to ping from the client to server IP on which the server is listening.  Meaning, I did a "ping <DIP> -i <SIP>" from my windows client and it works fine

Comment: There is no error message or anything shown too on the client side. So, I am not sure if any packet is being sent. However, I do see the server listening on the port using netstat. Also, like mentioned in the question, I can see the TCP connection happening when both the client and server scripts are sun on the same machine. So, I am assuming that some conf issue is there and issue might not be with respect to the code. Just a thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked. Thanks for your inputs. I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=5000/tcp
```